# Flutter Method Channels "Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method nativeMethod on channel com.example.myapp/methodChannel)"

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am making a vpn app in Android Studio / Flutter, and I need to communicate between flutter and native code (as flutter_openvpn package doesn't work anymore). I have set up a method channel for the flutter to communicate back and forth between but it won't even allow a simple connection between it and Kotlin. Flutter compiles fine, error only when button is pressed.
I am getting this error

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method connectOpenVPN on channel com.example.myapp/openvpn)
```

Here is the sample code I have for both.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Define a channel with the same name as on the native side
  final MethodChannel platform = MethodChannel('com.example.myapp/openvpn');

  Future<void> connectOpenVPN() async {
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('connectOpenVPN');
      print('OpenVPN Result: $result');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Error executing OpenVPN: ${e.message}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('OpenVPN Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              connectOpenVPN(); // Call the OpenVPN method here
            },
            child: Text('Connect to OpenVPN'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

that is flutter and this is the kotlin

```kotlin
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.myapp/openvpn"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            if (call.method == "connectOpenVPN") {
                val serverHostname = "example.com"
                val serverPort = 443
                val protocol = "udp"
                val username = "example"
                val password = "example"

                val openvpnCommand = "openvpn --remote $serverHostname $serverPort --proto $protocol --auth-user-pass <(echo -e '$username\n$password')"

                try {
                    val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", openvpnCommand)
                    val process = processBuilder.start()

                    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
                    val output = StringBuilder()
                    var line: String?
                    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                        output.append(line).append('\n')
                    }

                    val exitCode = process.waitFor()
                    val outputString = output.toString()

                    // Show a Toast message with OpenVPN output (optional)
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        showToast(this@MainActivity, "OpenVPN process exited with code: $exitCode\n$outputString")
                    }

                    result.success(outputString)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    result.error("COMMAND_ERROR", "Error executing OpenVPN command: ${e.message}", null)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    result.error("INTERRUPTED_ERROR", "Command execution interrupted: ${e.message}", null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showToast(context: Context, message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I saw some other threads have the same error occur but their solutions like restarting IDE, invalidating caches and cleaning flutter did not help at all. Perhaps I am missing something very obvious. My flutter code is in the /lib directory and the Kotlin is in the android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/vpn/MainActivity.kt  . I have used dummy variables for all of the names and details, the error is just with the method channel.

Please help so for now and future I understand where I've gone wrong. Thank you.